# Scheduling AWS RDS snapshot migrations

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to set up a process in which a postgres staging database is populated with production data.

I have some working implementation with `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` but I was wondering if something in RDS itself is possible.

We have nightly snapshots on our production database. My goal would be RDS takes the latest database snapshot, migrates it to an existing database and does this on some scheduled cadence (1/week or something like that).

Is this possible to configure in the console? If not are there some some combination of lambda/cloud formation that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

> My goal would be RDS takes the latest database snapshot, migrates it to an existing database

RDS never loads a snapshot into an existing database. It always creates an entirely new database server/cluster from a snapshot.

> Is this possible to configure in the console? If not are there some some combination of lambda/cloud formation that can do this?

You would have to write some code that creates a new staging database server from the production snapshot, and deletes your current server.

If you are using CloudFormation, then it could manage this for you if you specify the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` [parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-dbsnapshotidentifier). You would have to modify that parameter each week, and then update your CloudFormation stack.